# Logicmonitor - How to get the list of roles using API?

Tags: logic, monitor

I'm using Logic monitor in my project.I have created the user using Add account API. But there for each user we need to add role id. I'm giving role id manually. Is anyone know how to get the list of roles using API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, To get the list of roles from logicmonitor we have to use the HTTP request which is given below,

http://companyname.logicmonitor.com/santaba/rpc/getRoles?c=companyname&u=username&p=password

Answer (score 2):

Try with

```
$container->getParameter('security.role_hierarchy.roles');
```

Obviously, if you can't reach `$container`, you have to inject it to your `Logicmonitor` class

Comment: Logic monitor is monitoring of networks, servers, applications, storage, and cloud. For your reference (www.logicmonitor.com)